# How to copy a file with folder wildcard command line

Tags: windows, command-line

My goal with this post is to find out how I can copy my dll generated from one project and put it next to another project's exe that uses the dll without merging the build paths.

Right now, I'm using Visual Studio 2022's post build events to copy my engine dll to the project that uses the dll like so:

`copy /y "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).dll" "$(TargetDir)..\Sandbox\$(TargetName).dll"`

The `$(TargetDir)` macro becomes this filepath `C:\REMOVED\Programming\Engine\Engine\bin\Debug-Win32\Engine\`

The `$(TargetName)` macro becomes `Engine`

The solution I came up with is to use a wildcard for the folder name `Sandbox`, that way if my project is called something else I don't have to go back into the post-build settings and change that. It will also be helpful when I have multiple projects that use the dll.

But sadly this doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why:
`copy /y "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).dll" "$(TargetDir)..\*\$(TargetName).dll"`